# Does IBM have a cloud hosting service that can be used to host worklight server/applications?

Tags: deployment, cloud, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

In [IBM developer works blog](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/mobileblog/entry/use_ibm_pureapplication_system_to_deploy_ibm_worklight_in_the_cloud?lang=en), I have read a post on using IBM PureApplication system to deploy Worklight server and applications to cloud.

Does IBM have a cloud hosting service as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by looking at: http://www.ibm.com/cloud-computing/us/en/

IBM provides various ways to run the IBM MobileFirst Platform (formerly Worklight) as a hosted service.
Some of them are unmanaged (you have to do your own IT). Some are managed.

The basic option is to go to Softlayer and create an unmanaged Worklight instance.

Look at http://www.ibm.com/marketplace/cloud/mobile-application-platform-pattern/us/en-us which is how IBM provides Worklight as a service, hosted on Softlayer, installed via PureApplications managed below and services by IBM Global technology unit.

Finally, IBM is in the process of providing the Worklight as a fully managed, cloud service via the IBM cloud called "Bluemix" https://console.ng.bluemix.net/  . A beta of a mobile data service, push service, mobile analytics and mobile security will appear in Bluemix by the end of this week. Note that the latest option is currently for iOS apps only